how to do loop in snowflake
I have a SQL script while loop which I need to do same in snowflake.Can someone please help on this?I would really appreciate for a help.
CREATE FUNCTION [ezyVet].[fn_parseCommunicationContent](@originalcontent NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @content NVARCHAR(MAX)= @originalcontent
DECLARE @extracttext NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sol NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sol_refined NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE PATINDEX('%%',@content) > 1
BEGIN
SELECT @extracttext = SUBSTRING(@content, PATINDEX('%<li>%',@content), PATINDEX('%</li>%',@content)-PATINDEX('%<li>%',@content))+'</li>'

IF @sol IS NULL
    SET @sol = @extracttext
ELSE
    SET @sol = @sol + @extracttext 

IF @sol_refined IS NULL
    SELECT @sol_refined = IIF(DATEDIFF(MM,GETDATE(),TRY_CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(@extracttext,15),10) AS DATE))<=3,@extracttext,'')
ELSE
    SELECT @sol_refined = @sol_refined+IIF(DATEDIFF(MM,GETDATE(), TRY_CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(@extracttext,15),10) AS DATE))<=3,@extracttext,'')

SELECT @content = REPLACE(@content, @extracttext,'')

END
RETURN REPLACE(@originalcontent, @sol, @sol_refined)
END;

Hi - please format your code so that it is readable. Also, please add to your question the Snowflake code that you’ve managed to write so far and explain what the precise issue is that you’re facing
